# Using Actix Identity with Juniper GraphQL

Tags: rust, graphql, actix-web, juniper

I use [Actix Identity with Cookie Policy](https://docs.rs/actix-identity/0.3.0-alpha.1/actix_identity/index.html) to store user session and about to migrate from REST to GraphQL using [Juniper](https://github.com/graphql-rust/juniper).

It would be great to create a login endpoint in GraphQL by using `actix identity`.

Using Juniper in Actix, I've to move GraphQL request into `web::block`

```rust
actix_web::web::block(|| move {
    let graphql_response = request.execute(&data, &context);

    Ok::<_, serde_json::error::Error>(serde_json::to_string(&graphql_response)?)
})
```

Then pass Identity as `Juniper Context` to Juniper to execute query `login`.

```
struct Context {
    identity: Identity,
    connection_pool: DatabaseConnectionPool
}
```

The only problem is, I'm unable to pass `Actix Identity` to `web::block` because of threads safety.

```
std::rc::Rc<actix_web::request::HttpRequestInner>` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

Having the problem of unable to pass the `identity` to thread safety, I think of another solution.

By forcing Juniper to return an additional field to read outside thread of `web::block` and execute, for instance:

```
struct Result {
  data: Juniper_output_or_something,
  action: special_action_field_which_return_on_every_query_to_outside_thread_safety
}
```

The workaround I could think of is somehow passing Actix Identity into `web::block` or forcing Juniper to return additional field to execute outside `web::block`.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`Identity` encodes the data in a string, which you can pull out and pass around instead.

Change your `Context` to:

```
struct Context {
    identity: Option<String>,
    connection_pool: DatabaseConnectionPool,
}
```

And when you construct it, use `identity.identity()` to obtain the `Option<String>`.